# How do I cast an object to another object type with all the same properties except the new type has one more field

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, asp.net-core, casting

I am trying to cast the type skill to type SkillViewModel.

This is where I try the cast:

```
    SkillViewModel skillViewModel = (SkillViewModel)skill;
```

This is my skill model that I am trying to convert:

```
    public class Skill
    {
         public int SkillId { get; set; }
         public string SkillName { get; set; }
         public string SkillDescription { get; set; }
         public int SkillLevelId { get; set; }
         public string SkillLevelDescription { get; set; }
         public int LevelId { get; set; }
         public int LevelNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the SkillViewModel that I am trying to convert to. It inherits skill and has one added property RoleId:

```
    public class SkillViewModel : Skill
    {
         public int RoleId { get; set; }
    }
```

===========================================================================

## SOLVED:

Rather than casting the skill object to type SkillViewModel, I just created a new instance and explicitly copied each in the skill to the SkillViewModel added the roleId at the end.

Like this:

```
    private SkillViewModel[] GetRoleSpecificSkills(Skill[] skills, int roleId)
    {
        var results = new List<SkillViewModel>();

        foreach (var skill in skills)
        {
            SkillViewModel skillViewModel = new SkillViewModel();
            skillViewModel.SkillId = skill.SkillId;
            skillViewModel.SkillName = skill.SkillName;
            skillViewModel.SkillDescription = skill.SkillDescription;
            skillViewModel.SkillLevelId = skill.SkillLevelId;
            skillViewModel.SkillLevelDescription = skill.SkillLevelDescription;
            skillViewModel.LevelId = skill.LevelId;
            skillViewModel.LevelNumber = skill.LevelNumber;
            skillViewModel.RoleId = roleId;

            results.Add(skillViewModel);
        }

        return results.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: the solution you proposed works because all of your properties are public, which is a very bad style as it breaks [encapsulation rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28computer_programming%29) of object oriented programming. see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60054086/1220560) how to do it properly

Comment: I am using ASP.NET Core 3.0, the properties used are within models, should all properties in my models be private?

Comment: most often yes, but it is a very general question, hard to answer definitively. For example in my personal opinion it's sometimes ok to use public properties in simple data-transfer objects.

Answer (score 3):

You can't cast parent to child this way. And this is very bad practice.

If you **really** need to downcast, try this:

```
var jsonParent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parent); 
Child c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Child>(jsonParent);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, If it is bad practice I'll try and do it a different way

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you cannot cast from an incompatible type (such as a parent class) in C# nor any other statically typed programming language to that extent: a `Skill` object has a different representation in memory than a `SkillViewModel` object: `Skill`'s memory region is smaller by the size of the `RoleId` property, so if such casting is allowed by the compiler of a given language at all, then later if you try to access `RoleId`, it will result in a memory violation, because the offset of `RoleId` is beyond the boundary of the memory region allocated for the `Skill` object.

In case of converting from a parent class to a subclass, the best way is to create a constructor in `SkillViewModel` that takes a `Skill` object as a param, copies all its properties to its own instance variables and assigns some sane default value to the `RoleId`.
Note however that all these properties will now be referenced from 2 objects, so if any of them is mutable, then changing it in 1 object will also change it the second: this may have unexpected results sometimes, hence immutable objects are generally preferred whenever possible. Whenever you are making a new reference to a mutable object, you should consider making a deep clone of it instead: take into consideration performance and memory usage penalty on one hand and likeliness of someone making a bug on the other.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reach RoleID property when you cast it like this:

```
SkillViewModel skillViewModel = skill as SkillViewModel;
```

Comment: No, skillViewModel variable will have null value in your example.

Comment: I probably misunderstood the question. Isn't it obvious that parent class doesn't have that information?

Comment: It is for me. But not to author.